# Can't convert one generic list to another

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4, compiler-errors

I have the following list:

```
List<view_zoodoffers> list = sqlEntities.viewOffers
    .Where(o => o.ProductId == productId)
    .GroupBy(o => o.OfferId)
    .ToList();
```

`OfferId` is `long`:  I get the following error when I try to convert the list:

`Error  27  Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<long,myDAL.viewOffers>> to System.Collections.Generic.List<myDAL.viewOffers>`:

What am I doing wrong?

I want the functionality like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ViewOffers group by offerid
```

Comment: That's a bad class name; it should be called `ViewOffer`.

Comment: Yes class name is ViewOffer, ViewOffer is a view i am getting records and now i want to get records group by offerId. it works fine when i group by using query.

Comment: i want this functionality "SELECT * FROM ViewOffers
group by offerid"

Comment: Sami: Have you tried to run this query against SQL server manually? You will get an error. However you can run `SELECT offerid FROM ViewOffers group by offerid`

Comment: the SQL 'group by' keeps just one item per group. The LINQ GroupBy retains all items, only grouped according to (the result of) the lambda expression.

Comment: yes i have run this query manually and this shows me records without any error.

Comment: Sami: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4):

As the error message *clearly* states, `GroupBy` is returning a list of `IGrouping`s, which isn't the same as a list of `ViewOffer`s.

You can get a single element from each group by adding `.Select(g => g.Last())`

Answer (score 1):

You can't put "result of grouping of x" into "list of x"!

Use

```
List<IGrouping<long,myDAL.viewOffers>> list =
```

or just

```
var list = ...
```

---

That's what you need:

```
sqlEntities.viewOffers
    .Where(o => o.ProductId == productId)
    .GroupBy(o => o.OfferId)
    .Select(o => o.Key);
```

or

```
sqlEntities.viewOffers
    .Where(o => o.ProductId == productId)
    .Select(o => o.OfferId)
    .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using GroupBy extension method you're getting list of grouped items where each group is enumerable of elements with same OfferId.That's why you have `'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Linq.IGrouping<long,myDAL.viewOffers>>'` as a result of your operation. Look into [IGouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) documentation.